# Adjust GridView (ControlsFx) height depending on item count

Tags: java, gridview, javafx, controlsfx

I want to make a [GridView](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) resize itself to a value big enough to fit the height of its content so no scrollbar is needed (I want the gridbar together with other nodes in a scrollbar, see image).

[GridView in Scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVACI.jpg)

But there isn't any possibility to get at least the number of rows to calculate the needed height.

Comment: Will a [`FlowPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html) work?

Comment: I want to use the feature of binding a model class to the GridView, what would be a problem if I use a FlowPane (not sure about that).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set any height value, the default behaviour is to fit the content.
Or you could do this:

```
gridView.setPrefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
```

Comment: I can retrace this behavior on initialization of the GridView. But if I resize the window the GridView height keeps as before and a scrollBar appears.

Comment: I do not understand what is the behavior that you are describing. If you resize the window to a smaller size, what behavior do you expect?

Comment: I want the size (height) of the GridView to grow up so that the scrollPane of the GridView doesn't show up.